# Trying to access node REPL produces Error: Cannot find module 'esm'

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04.1 and I just installed the current version of node trough nvm (14.8.0), now when trying to access the node REPL by just typing `node`,  I got this error message:

```sh
$ node
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1083
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'esm'
Require stack:
- internal/preload
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:923:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1140:19)
    at Module._preloadModules (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1397:12)
    at loadPreloadModules (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:446:5)
    at prepareMainThreadExecution (internal/bootstrap/pre_execution.js:74:3)
    at internal/main/repl.js:19:1 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'internal/preload' ]
}
```

Any advice about what's going on and how to fix it is welcome

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering my own question in the event someone else faces the same problem: To access the node REPL just install the esm package globally:

```
npm install -g esm
```

Or if just require the packae for a project, whitin yout project folder:

```
npm i esm
```

For more informatión check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm).